# Calculated column being changed on save

Tags: calculated-column

I need to keep the URL of a list item to use in a notification so I have a formula that looks like this:

```
="http://basicsample.com/next/List/EditItem?ID="&[ID]
```

When I create an item in the list, in this case item 24, the column is formatted correctly as:

```
http://basicsample.com/next/List/EditItem?ID=24
```

But when I go into the list item and edit some other attribute, say the status, the URL is now:

```
http://basicsample.com/next/LIst/EditItem?ID=
```

The item id, 24, has been dropped.  If I go check the formula it is now:

```
="http://basicsample.com/next/List/EditItem?ID="&ID
```

The brackets have been dropped from the formula.

Any ideas on what is going on and how to prevent?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the ID in a calculated column. You can try using a workflow to build a dynamic string and set a text field with the value you require.